# Javascript gallery with prev/next function AND thumbnail... nothing else

Tags: javascript, html, css

Short of going for something like [Galleriffic](http://www.twospy.com/galleriffic/index.html)

and modifying, hiding and removing elements, what would be a way to add a function by which thumbnails can also be clicked to display the image?

Much obliged to anyone who can point me in the right direction. I'm using the following by Paul McFedries at mcfedries.com.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
// Use the following variable to specify 
// the number of images
var NumberOfImages = 3

var img = new Array(NumberOfImages)

// Use the following variables to specify the image names:
img[0] = "yellow1.jpg"
img[1] = "blue2.jpg"
img[2] = "green3.jpg"


var imgNumber = 0

function NextImage()
{
    imgNumber++
    if (imgNumber == NumberOfImages)
        imgNumber = 0
    document.images["VCRImage"].src = img[imgNumber]
}

function PreviousImage()
{
    imgNumber--
    if (imgNumber < 0)
        imgNumber = NumberOfImages - 1
    document.images["VCRImage"].src = img[imgNumber]
}

</script>
```

in the html:

```
    <div class="galleryarrows">
<A HREF="javascript:PreviousImage()">
<IMG SRC="previous.png" BORDER=0></A>
<A HREF="javascript:NextImage()">
<IMG SRC="next.png" BORDER=0></A>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick, basic solution: Save the full size versions of your images in a folder called say, 'full_images', with the same names as the thumbnails.

Add an onClick event into the element img elements that display your thumbnails in the html, so they look something like this.

```
<img src = "yellow1.jpg" name = "thumb[0]" style = "cursor:pointer" onClick = "Javascript:DisplayImage(0);" alt = "yellow"/>
<img src = "blue2.jpg" name = "thumb[1]" style = "cursor:pointer" onClick = "Javascript:DisplayImage(1);"  alt = "blue"/>
<img src = "green3.jpg" name = "thumb[2]" style = "cursor:pointer" onClick = "Javascript:DisplayImage(2);"  alt = "green"/>
```

In your javascript, add this function

```
function DisplayImage(id){
       imgNumber = id;
       document.images["VCRImage"].src = "full_images/" + img[id];
```

}

This will display in an element with the name 'VCRImage'.

Not my favourite solution this, but quick, and should work. If Javascript is new to you, then you might as well check out [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com). It's a lot easier to use, and is way more cross-browser compatible.

Comment: Thanks, Charlie. Arrows and thumbs are clickable but it seems the prev/next function doesn't recognize which image is presently displayed. Try the following: start on img1, click NEXT leads to img2 (so far so good) but then click thumbnail 1 to go back to img1... clicking NEXT will take you to img3 when it should go to img2.

Comment: Ok, in that case, you need to store the index of the current image as well. A simple way would be to add a hidden field `code`<input type = "hidden" name = "currentImg" value = "" />`code` into your html. In your

Comment: thanks again for the help. I'm still quite new at this... I should put this code only once, into the same div as my thumbnail images, just before the images, right? I've been trying, but I'm afraid I can't figure out what to do with currentImg and value=""

Comment: sorry, that comment posted before it was finished. I may have misunderstood. It seems that VCRImage is your main gallery image right, and you have previous and next arrows to cycle through the collection of images? Or you can click on a thumbnail to jump to one in the collection? Assuming this is the case, I will edit my answer for you.

Comment: I'll give that a try, thank you so much. the image gallery is now online at http://luxe-deluxe.com/collections/winter2011.html with another script, which although elegant - only one set of images needed-, doesn't seem to work on Safari 5 on mac... where as the script above did. i might make a new question for that, and yea I definitely have to look into jquery to start building good code on my own.